# Bug when registering to stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, login, stackexchange.com

I'm a new user that has logged in many sites of the stackexchange community, including [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), however when I try to log in in [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/) I see a white screen which says:

> Completing log in to Stack Exchange
> You will be redirected automatically

And I've waited a long time many times, but nothing happened.
I don't know what's wrong, but I don't see either sign in button or join this community button.
What can I do to solve this?

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Clean cookies
2. Go to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and register using GitHub (I use GitHub for my account)
3. Go to your profile
4. Click on network profile
5. Press log in button
6. The bug appears

I think that my account uses github is relevant, since if I try to login here after cleaning cookies there is not Sign In using GitHub button.

Steps 3-4 are only for getting to [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/), it doesn't work in any way and I think that is the fastest.

#### Browsers

1. In Chrome 84.0.4147.105 I don't get ever redirected.
2. In Firefox 68.11.0esr I get redirected to the same page but without logging in.
3. In Firefox developer 79.0b9 it works like in Opera and Edge (also surprising because it doesn't have Log In with GitHub option in [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/))
4. <strike>In Opera 69.0.3686.95 there is no Sign In with GitHub even in [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/)</strike> Oops, I was trying Spanisth StackOverflow, I just realised that and now:
   In Opera 70.0.3728.71 It works perfectly like in edge (also surprising because it doesn't have Log In with GitHub option in [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/))
5. In Edge 84.0.522.49 it works perfectly (surprising because it doesn't have Log In with GitHub option in [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/))

Comment: I just logged out and in again on stackexchange.com and only saw that page for a split second. Could it be an issue on your end? Perhaps you are running some script or extension that is interfering with the redirect? What OS and browser do you use?

Comment: At first I saw the error "Forbidden by antivirus", but whitelisting the site and blocking the cookies haven't made it works. I'll edit and add my steps to reproduce.

Comment: Did you try disabling your antivirus altogether before logging in? It looks like your antivirus is blocking something and it would be better to try and rule that out if it's not the cause. Maybe also try to run your browser in safe-mode (without plugins or extensions).

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Yes, but since I use GitHub to log in and there is not Sign in with GitHub button I can't log in. I guess this issue has to do with the fact that I used GitHub to Sign Up.

Comment: I agree that most likely it's because you're using Github login. We should find someone else using such login and see if they can also reproduce.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask I think so, but surprisingly Edge works and I don't have a clue of what's the real problem.

Comment: So it means it's something with the cookies... I'm afraid only SE developer can take it from here. In the meantime you can add another login and use it in order to be logged in to se.com

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask I'll do that, and it will probably work, however it's a temporary solution because I want to use GitHub in all sites I can.

Comment: Of course, but with a small amount of developers, and high amount of bug reports, it just takes time for them to check and fix those bugs.